# Creating row identifier within a group

Tags: r, group-by, identifier, mutate

I have data in the following form. There are more than a million rows. I just want to create another column which helps me in row identification of grouped Item3 . The first two columns are irrelevant. Just added to let know that I have other columns in the dataset. I used cumsum and group_indices but didn't work.

| Item1 | Item2 | Item3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | A |
| One | Two | A |
| One | Two | A |
| One | Two | B |
| One | Two | B |
| One | Two | C |

| Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Identifier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | A | 1 |
| One | Two | A | 2 |
| One | Two | A | 3 |
| One | Two | B | 1 |
| One | Two | B | 2 |
| One | Two | C | 1 |

Comment: Use `library(data.table); dt$Identifier <- rowid(dt$Item3)`

Comment: Using the `dplyr` package: `group_by(df, Item1, Item2, Item3) %>% mutate(Identifier=1:n())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(
  Item1 = c("One", "One", "One", "One", "One", "One"),
  Item2 = c("Two", "Two", "Two", "Two", "Two", "Two"),
  Item3 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C")
)

data %>% 
  mutate(ID = row_number(), .by = Item3))

  Item1 Item2 Item3     ID
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
1 One   Two   A         1
2 One   Two   A         2
3 One   Two   A         3
4 One   Two   B         1
5 One   Two   B         2
6 One   Two   C         1
```

Credit to [Chamkrai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17213355/chamkrai) for the `.by = Item3` idea

Comment: Please add `dplyr` to your required libraries.

Comment: Nice! Btw - you can skip `group_by()` now after the new update `data %>% mutate(ID = row_number(), .by = Item3)`

Comment: nice! I did not know that  you learn something new every day

Answer (score 0):

### Base solution

```
ave(integer(nrow(data)), data$Item3, FUN = seq_along)
```

### data.table solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, ID := rowidv(Item3)]
```

## Data

```
structure(list(Item1 = c("One", "One", "One", "One", "One", "One"
), Item2 = c("Two", "Two", "Two", "Two", "Two", "Two"), Item3 = c("A", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "C")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```